# How do I get user input in a GUI using text field?

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextfield, user-input

I'm working on a project that needs a GUI. How do I get the input for two given strings from the user using JTextField and display the output?

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s ;
    System.out.println("Enter the Barcode:");

    s = user_input.next();
    String z;
    System.out.println("Enter the Serial Number:");

    z = user_input.next();
    Random r = new Random();
    int low = 1;
    int high = 21;// Set the number of random methods
    int rand = r.nextInt(high - (low - 1)) + low;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't mix GUI with console.

- If you have no idea how to create GUIs and no real experience with Swing, and you want to learn, you will need to learn the Event driven model, and how event and listeners work, as they are the backbone of GUI programming. You can start with the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- If you are just running a console program, and want to get the user input from a graphical interface, maybe you should just look into something simple like a `JOptionPane`. You can look at the [JOptionPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html). You could do something like

  ```
  String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                null, "What's your answer to this question?");
  System.out.println(input);
  ```

  [image]

You can see how to make more complex dialogs at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Netbeans IDE](https://netbeans.org) with its GUI builder space and drag o drop every component you want, for example button, label, textfield, list, combo box, ...

as you see:

[image]